# Apply different functions to elements in array of arrays in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to apply some functions to certain elements in an array of arrays.

```
def func_1(num):
    return num+1

def func_2(num):
    return num+2

test_array = [ [10,1],[10,1],[11,2]]
```

I want to apply function `func_1` to first element of each array and function `func_2` to second element of each array.

The result array will look like this;

```
result_array = [ [11,3],[11,3],[12,4]]
```

I am using python 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map()`:

```
def func_1(num):
    return num+1

def func_2(num):
    return num+2

test_array = [ [10,1],[10,1],[11,2]]

out = list(map(lambda x: [func_1(x[0]), func_2(x[1])], test_array))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[11, 3], [11, 3], [12, 4]]
```

Or using comprehension:

```
out = [[func_1(x), func_2(y)]  for x, y in test_array]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's rather above my level. I'm not familiar with map and lambda. Your one-liner answer looks simple, yet complex :)

Comment: @user3848207 I added the list comprehension, it's easier to do it with it

Answer (score 3):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [[func_1(x0), func_2(x1)] for x0, x1 in test_array]
[[11, 3], [11, 3], [12, 4]]
```

Or without unpacking: `[[func_1(x[0]), func_2(x[1])] for x in test_array]`